# FreeRTOS Error with High Speed UART Interrupt in PIC24H

Tags: c, multithreading, stm32, mplab, freertos

I already used `FreeRTOS` for some embedded projects for some year time and It worked really perfectly until now. Currently i'm facing a difficult problem related to using High Speed Interrupt in `FreeRTOS` porting to `PIC24H`, hope you all can help me to though this problem. Thanks in advance

I created a small demo project for easy testing:

Two task:

```
// Task 1

if (xTaskCreate(RTOSTask_1, (signed char) "[T1]", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE2, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1, &hTask1) == errCOULD_NOT_ALLOCATE_REQUIRED_MEMORY)
{
  LREP("\r\nCannot create Task 1.");   
  Display_Error(1000);
}

// Task 2

if (xTaskCreate(RTOSTask_2, (signed char) "[T2]", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE2, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 2, &hTask2) == errCOULD_NOT_ALLOCATE_REQUIRED_MEMORY)
{
  LREP("\r\nCannot create Task 2."); 
  Display_Error(1000);  
}
```

Implementation of tasks:

```
void RTOSTask_1(void* pvParameter)
{ 
  while(1)
  {

    if (xSemaphoreTake(hTask1Semaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE)
    { 
      putchar1('1');
    } 
  }
}

void RTOSTask_2(void* pvParameter)
{
  while(1)
  {
    if (xSemaphoreTake(hTask2Semaphore, portMAX_DELAY) == pdTRUE)
    { 
       putchar1('2');
    } 

   }
}
```

To let above two tasks running i use one `Timer` & one `UART` to give them Semaphores:

```
void attribute((interrupt, auto_psv)) _T2Interrupt (void)
{ 
  _T2IF = 0;
  static signed portBASE_TYPE xTaskWoken = pdFALSE;
  xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(hTask1Semaphore, &xTaskWoken );

  if( xTaskWoken != pdFALSE )
  {
    taskYIELD();
  }
}

void attribute((interrupt, auto_psv)) _U1TXInterrupt()
{

  _U1TXIF = 0;
  putchar1('E');
} 

void attribute((interrupt, auto_psv)) _U1RXInterrupt()
{

  _U1RXIF = 0;
  if(U1STAbits.URXDA == 1)
  {
    uint8 u8Recv = U1RXREG;
  }

  static signed portBASE_TYPE xTaskWoken;

  xTaskWoken = pdFALSE;

  xSemaphoreGiveFromISR(hTask2Semaphore, &xTaskWoken);


  if( xTaskWoken != pdFALSE )
  {
    taskYIELD();
  }
}
```

My Timer interrupts in every 100us, UART working at 230400 bps baudrate speed.

After running some second or minutes the program is crashed and the program jump to Traps:

`_AddressError` or

`_StackError`

I don't know how this problem could happen. After a long investigating & testing i thought that the problem happen when the program running in & running out of the Interrupt service routine (ISR). It seems we need a couple of `SAVE_CONTEXT()` & `RESTORE_CONTEXT()` functions. but on PIC24 port there is no one like that.

Please you kindly give me some advises for this problem

Thank you all !

---

I already find out my problem, i think. The problem is introduced when the PIC24H gets in & gets out Interrupt Service Routines, here they are UART RX, TX, Timer Interrupts.

Currently i don't use the ISR like this:

void **attribute**((**interrupt**, auto_psv))

instead of it i created a mechanism myself with Assembly code:

__U1RXInterrupt:
        ; Push CPU registers in to Stack

```
    PUSH    SR          
PUSH    W0
PUSH    W1          
PUSH.D  W2
PUSH.D  W4
PUSH.D  W6
PUSH.D  W8
PUSH.D  W10
PUSH.D  W12
PUSH    W14
PUSH    RCOUNT
PUSH    TBLPAG
PUSH    CORCON
PUSH    PSVPAG

    ; Call my ISR
    call _UART1_RxISRHandler        

    ; Pop out CPU registers
POP PSVPAG
POP CORCON
POP TBLPAG
POP RCOUNT                  
POP W14
POP.D   W12
POP.D   W10
POP.D   W8
POP.D   W6
POP.D   W4
POP.D   W2
POP.D   W0
POP SR


retfie
```

UART1_RxISRHandler is my implement of ISR. I do the same with TX, Timer interrupts.

The result is that my program run more smoothly, longer 1 hour (before the program crash after 1-5 minutes only). But at the end it still crash after running 1-2 hours. That means my approach is correct but still there is something wrong. May be i miss something with above code.

If you all have any ideal for this situation, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Well, instigating a thread-switch by signaling a semaphore for every char at 230400 baud is quite a loading.  Can you buffer up the rx chars and so reduce the semaphore signaling?

Comment: Dear James iknow that is better but i think for this demo case the FreeRTOS still should work normally.

Comment: One char, and one scheduling run, every 43us :(   What does putchar1() do?

Comment: Can you show your semaphores and interrupt initialization code?

Answer (score 2):

I've got a similar problem.

What is the priority of your uart interrupt ?

It should not be higher than the RTOS Kernel interrupt priority set into the FreeRTOSConfig.h which has a default priority of 1 while PIC interrupt have a default priority of 3.

This seem to have caused a very occasionally crash.

The SAVE_CONTEXT() & RESTORE_CONTEXT() are not necessary with PIC as the compiler takes car of that, at least if you are using the compiler function declaration and avoid using _FASTISR or shadowing.

Answer (score 1):

Try using queues.
Example for this on LPC1769. You can easily port it for your mcu.

> ## define mainQUEUE_LENGTH ( 1 )

This will fix maximum bytes that can be stored in queue. Modify this as per your requirement and hence will immune from stack error or address error
:

```
#include "FreeRTOS.h"
#include "task.h"
#include "queue.h"

/* Priorities at which the tasks are created. */
#define mainQUEUE_RECEIVE_TASK_PRIORITY     ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 2 )
#define mainQUEUE_SEND_TASK_PRIORITY        ( tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 1 )

/* The bit of port 0 that the LPCXpresso LPC13xx LED is connected. */
#define mainLED_BIT                         ( 22 )

/* The rate at which data is sent to the queue, specified in milliseconds. */
#define mainQUEUE_SEND_FREQUENCY_MS         ( 500 / portTICK_RATE_MS )

/* The number of items the queue can hold.  This is 1 as the receive task
will remove items as they are added, meaning the send task should always find
the queue empty. */
#define mainQUEUE_LENGTH                    ( 1 )

/*
 * The tasks as described in the accompanying PDF application note.
 */
static void prvQueueReceiveTask( void *pvParameters );
static void prvQueueSendTask( void *pvParameters );

/*
 * Simple function to toggle the LED on the LPCXpresso LPC17xx board.
 */
static void prvToggleLED( void );

/* The queue used by both tasks. */
static xQueueHandle xQueue = NULL;

/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

int main(void)
{
    /* Initialise P0_22 for the LED. */
    LPC_PINCON->PINSEL1 &= ( ~( 3 << 12 ) );
    LPC_GPIO0->FIODIR |= ( 1 << mainLED_BIT );

    /* Create the queue. */
    xQueue = xQueueCreate( mainQUEUE_LENGTH, sizeof( unsigned long ) );

    if( xQueue != NULL )
    {
        /* Start the two tasks as described in the accompanying application
        note. */
        xTaskCreate( prvQueueReceiveTask, ( signed char * ) "Rx", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, mainQUEUE_RECEIVE_TASK_PRIORITY, NULL );
        xTaskCreate( prvQueueSendTask, ( signed char * ) "TX", configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE, NULL, mainQUEUE_SEND_TASK_PRIORITY, NULL );

        /* Start the tasks running. */
        vTaskStartScheduler();
    }

    /* If all is well we will never reach here as the scheduler will now be
    running.  If we do reach here then it is likely that there was insufficient
    heap available for the idle task to be created. */
    for( ;; );
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

static void prvQueueSendTask( void *pvParameters )
{
portTickType xNextWakeTime;
const unsigned long ulValueToSend = 100UL;

    /* Initialise xNextWakeTime - this only needs to be done once. */
    xNextWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();

    for( ;; )
    {
        /* Place this task in the blocked state until it is time to run again.
        The block state is specified in ticks, the constant used converts ticks
        to ms.  While in the blocked state this task will not consume any CPU
        time. */
        vTaskDelayUntil( &xNextWakeTime, mainQUEUE_SEND_FREQUENCY_MS );

        /* Send to the queue - causing the queue receive task to flash its LED.
        0 is used as the block time so the sending operation will not block -
        it shouldn't need to block as the queue should always be empty at this
        point in the code. */
        xQueueSend( xQueue, &ulValueToSend, 0 );
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

static void prvQueueReceiveTask( void *pvParameters )
{
unsigned long ulReceivedValue;

    for( ;; )
    {
        /* Wait until something arrives in the queue - this task will block
        indefinitely provided INCLUDE_vTaskSuspend is set to 1 in
        FreeRTOSConfig.h. */
        xQueueReceive( xQueue, &ulReceivedValue, portMAX_DELAY );

        /*  To get here something must have been received from the queue, but
        is it the expected value?  If it is, toggle the LED. */
        if( ulReceivedValue == 100UL )
        {
            prvToggleLED();
        }
    }
}
/*-----------------------------------------------------------*/

static void prvToggleLED( void )
{
unsigned long ulLEDState;

    /* Obtain the current P0 state. */
    ulLEDState = LPC_GPIO0->FIOPIN;

    /* Turn the LED off if it was on, and on if it was off. */
    LPC_GPIO0->FIOCLR = ulLEDState & ( 1 << mainLED_BIT );
    LPC_GPIO0->FIOSET = ( ( ~ulLEDState ) & ( 1 << mainLED_BIT ) );
}
```

Comment: I have successfully ported this on ATMEL SAM3X, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a stack overrun.
How much stack are you allocating for each task?

Since FreeRTOS interrupt handler shares a stack with FreeRTOS task (AFAIK, there is no system stack), it can easily cause overrun when stack usage of both a task and a handler adds up.

Since any task could be running when interrupt kicks in, this leads to sporadic behavior as a task's stack usage at the point of interrupt differs.

To check it, you can simply increase stack allocation size of ALL tasks, including implicitly-created IDLE task (and other system tasks, if configured to use one). Or, you can add following to your code to catch stack overrun:

```
// in FreeRTOSConfig.h
#define configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW 1

=== somewhere in your code ===
void vApplicationStackOverflowHook(TaskHandle_t xTask, char *pcTaskName) {
    // Embed assembler code to put your processor into debughalt state.
    // I'm not familiar with PIC24 asm, but
    //
    // - http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=434136
    //
    // may help.
    MACRO_TO_DEBUG_HALT();
}
```